# Is it possible that scrapy use Phantomjs directly to download the page source to render？

Tags: scrapy

In my CustomDownloaderMiddleware:

```
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if spider.name == 'UrlSpider':
            res = requests.get(request.url)
            return HtmlResponse(request.url, body=res.content, encoding='utf-8', request=request)
```

I want to render the *reponse.body* in def process_response, What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a scrapy middleware that will do exactly this: it will run your Requests through PhantomJS and your responses will contain the rendered html.

You find it here and it works quite well for me (though it is not so well tested according to its author): https://github.com/brandicted/scrapy-webdriver

If you aren't bound to PhantomJS, you might also have a look into https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash as this much better maintained (by the same people that develop scrapy).

**Update**

If you want to scrape only some pages through PhantomJS, I see two potential ways to do this:

1. It is most probably possible to do some Javascript magic to inject the html from your `response.body` into PhantomJS and make it render this page.

This would be exactly what you want, but it might be a bit difficult to get this right. (have been doing some Javascript magic with PhantomJS and it's often not as easy as I had hoped for).

2. You could register the PhantomJS downloader in parallel to the standard middleware and load those pages you want to render a second time, but this time through the PhantomJS downloader.

For this activate the PhantomJS downloader as follows in `settings.py`:

```
# note the 'js-' in front of http
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    'js-http': 'scrapy_webdriver.download.WebdriverDownloadHandler',
    'js-https': 'scrapy_webdriver.download.WebdriverDownloadHandler',
}
```

And then in your parse method:

```
def parse(self, response):
    if should_be_rendered(response):
        phantom_url = response.url.replace("http", "js-http")
        # do the same request again but this time through the WebdriverDownloadHandler
        yield Request(phantom_url, ...)
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for you answer very much. And My question is that I have run the Request, I want to render the page source after get the Response.I don't know if it is feasible.

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure whether I'm understanding your question correctly. What I know (and have been doing & using): the above mentioned middleware does not render the page source **after** getting the response. Instead it makes phantomjs download and render the page and then **afterwards** builds a response object from the rendered page. Is this suitable for your needs?

Comment: Thank you again.What I want to do is that after getting a **Response**, I want to render the **Response.body**

Comment: Just to clarify: The approach I suggest will automagically give you response objects where Response.body is already rendered through PhantomJS. Would this work for you? If not, maybe a few more details about what you want to accomplish and why would help.

Comment: I don't want render every webpage, I want to only render some webpage, so I want to check the content of **Response.body** to decide whether render it

Comment: It seem like the answer I want. but I have a confuse about **DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES** and **DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS**, I don't konw when to use the **DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS **, if in my **DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES** call the _process_request_:                                                                                         `def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if spider.name == 'UrlSpider':
            res = requests.get(request.url)
            return HtmlResponse(request.url, body=res.content, encoding='utf-8', request=request)` , then the  **DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS ** wiil be called ?

Comment: After some tries，I think that **DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS** work for _downloader_ to handle a _request_. **DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES** is used to handle request between **Scheduler** and **Downloader**, it can do these things:set request.meta[xx]:'xx' or directly handle the _request_ by the import **requests** (if do that, the _request_ won't arrival **Downloader** )

Comment: Exactly. DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS do the final step of downloading an URL and there is only one per protocol. DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES do process all Requests and a Request usually is processed by multiple if not all DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES.